# Filling all rows with respective group mean (ddply?)

Tags: r, plyr

Probably a silly question about a simple task for `ddply`, but strangely enough I could not find the solution. So, let's say I have a dataframe, containing respondents within countries, and a number of jobs that the respondent has held in his or her career:

```
mydata <- structure(list(country = structure(c(11L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 
7L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 13L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 3L), contrasts = structure(c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1), .Dim = c(13L, 
12L), .Dimnames = list(c("Austria", "Germany", "Sweden", "Netherlands", 
"Spain", "Italy", "France", "Denmark", "Greece", "Switzerland", 
"Belgium", "Czechia", "Poland"), c("AT", "DE", "SE", "NL", "ES", 
"IT", "FR", "DK", "GR", "CH", "BE", "CZ"))), .Label = c("Austria", 
"Germany", "Sweden", "Netherlands", "Spain", "Italy", "France", 
"Denmark", "Greece", "Switzerland", "Belgium", "Czechia", "Poland"
), class = "factor"), njobs = c(2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 
2, 3, 3, 2, 8, 3, 1, 2, 9, 3)), .Names = c("country", "njobs"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I would like to add a third column variable, containing an average number of jobs in a career *in that particular country*. This is easy to do in two lines:

```
ctry.means <- ddply(mydata,.(country),summarize,avejobs=mean(njobs))
result <- merge(mydata,ctry.means,by="country")
```

However, this is such a simple and frequently used operation, that I feel there must be a simpler way to do it in one step, some trick with `ddply`. In a more general case this relates to combining group-level and case-level variables in a single `summarize` or `mutate` statement.

Comment: Just use `transform/mutate` instead of `summarize`.

Comment: I knew I was being dumb about it :) Thanks @Ramnath

Comment: Or with dplyr: `mydata %.% group_by(country) %.% mutate(avejobs = mean(njobs))`

Comment: @hadley After this I have no choice but take a look at your new dplyr package :)

Answer (score 1):

if you're happy with a simple base solution,

```
mydata$new = ave(mydata$njobs, mydata$country)
```

will do that too.